# Are there any wallets that can call contracts?

Tags: smart-contracts, wallets, dapps

I'm building a dapp on Tezos and would like users to call some of the related contracts directly from the webapp. E.g. I present a QR code with a prefilled contract call. Are there any wallets that can handle this type of transaction yet? Or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Eventually this will come but not yet to my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [Galleon](https://galleon-wallet.tech/) just added support for [calling contracts](https://medium.com/the-cryptonomic-aperiodical/galleon-v0-8-0b-release-notes-c286978e7ffd)  Seems like this is something most wallets has not gotten around to yet.

I will encourage anyone who stumbled across one that support it to add a comment to this answer with a link

Thanks!

Comment: At the moment Galleon does not allow the user to change the network from Mainnet. If you add a custom Alphanet node to the Galleon settings then this message comes up - 'It seems the Tezos node you are using is either stuck or on the wrong network. Please delay further actions.'